# Derivative of riemann map from the unit disk to a Jordan domain with non rectifiable boundary

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $\gamma$ be  Jordan curve such that for each point $p \in \gamma$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\gamma \cap U$ is non rectifiable. Let $\phi: \mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ be a conformal map where $\Omega$ is the region bounded by $\gamma$. Then what can we say about the derivative $\phi'$ ?

Any references and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

As a consequence of the Koebe one-quarter theorem, if $\phi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow{\Omega}$ is conformal, you have upper and lower bounds on the derivative at any point:
$$\frac{\text{dist}(\phi(z),\partial{\Omega})}{(1-|z|^{2})}\leq{|\phi'(z)|}\leq{4\frac{\text{dist}(\phi(z),\partial{\Omega})}{(1-|z|^{2})}}$$ (see Theorem 4.3 of "Harmonic Measure" by Garnett and Marshall). This gives us the naive upper bound:
$$
|\phi'(z)|\leq{4\frac{\text{diam}(\Omega)}{(1-|z|^{2})}}
$$
That said, in complex analysis, there's a heuristic that if you have a conformal map $\phi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow{\Omega}$, the regularity of your boundary $\partial{\Omega}$ implies regularity for the corresponding conformal map $\phi$. I don't think you can say much better than what is given to you by the distortion theorem if all you know is that $\partial{\Omega}$ is a Jordan curve (and a non- rectifiable one at that), however, if $\gamma:S^{1}\rightarrow{\mathbb{C}}$ is a parametrization of $\partial{\Omega}$ and you know something about the modulus of continuity of $\gamma$, you can improve on the naive distortion theorem estimate.

Namely, if $\Omega$ is a Jordan domain, we know that our conformal map $\phi$ extends continuously to $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Hence, by Cauchy's integral formula:
$$
\phi(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\oint_{\partial{\mathbb{D}}}\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\gamma(t)}{e^{it}-z}e^{it}dt
$$
$$
\implies \phi'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\gamma(t)}{(e^{it}-z)^{2}}e^{it}dt
$$
Playing with this formula for $\phi'(z)$ in terms of $\gamma(t)$ we have that:
$$
|\phi'(z)|\leq{\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\omega(1-|z|)}{1-|z|}+2\pi\int_{1-|z|}^{\pi}\frac{\omega(t)}{t^{2}}dt}
$$
(see Proposition 3.4 of Pommerenke's "Boundary Behavior of Conformal Maps"). Here $\omega(t)$ is the modulus of continuity of $\gamma(t)$:
$$
\omega(\delta)=\max\{|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)|:s,t\in{S^{1}}, |s-t|\leq{\delta}\}
$$

Comment: Excellent answer. Since the boundary is nowhere rectifiable, I'm expecting more lower bounds on the derivate.